# TinyMce 4 - How to get an image on menu button

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Here's a [link](http://codepen.io/imnithin/pen/bajpA), where I want to get an image, inplace of '**image here?**' *text* .There is an option named **icon**, tried providing the image path located in the system in different ways, that didn't work out, so any help.

A down arrow kind of image.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps, icon receives the url to the icon, if you don't want text then leave text blank, if your using wordpress you can use dash icons by specifying a class for the icon then enqueue the css in wp admin, make sense ?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
  setup: function(editor) {
      editor.addButton('report_design', {
        type: 'menubutton',//leave empty if only want icon
        text: ' LEAVE BLANK ',
        icon: 'YOURclassHERE',//add class for css use or url to icon
        menu: [
          {text:'Data', menu:[{text:'sub1'},{text:'sub2'}], onclick: function() {editor.insertContent('text');}}
            ]
      });
    },

    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | emoticons | forecolor backcolor | print | report_design "

});
```

for the url you could try `var icon_url = 'path-to-icon-here';`